# How to replace field names in a dataframe with a vector in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have two dataframes and I am trying to use one character vector from one dataframe for the field names of the other dataframe.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c(1,2,3,4), a2 = c(5,6,7,8))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("a1","a2"), name = c("one","two"))
```

I want to replace the field names of df1 with the character vector df2$name to get:

```
one two
  1   5
  2   6
  3   7
  4   8
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Try ```names(df1) <- df2$name```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the index of matching elements between the column names of 'df1 and the 'ID' column of 'df2' and use that to get the corresponding 'name' from 'df2' and assign it to the column names of 'df1'

```
names(df1) <- df2$name[match(names(df1), df2$ID)]
```